# ColdFusion Query to java.sql.ResultSet

Tags: java, coldfusion, resultset

I've looked in the ["undocumentation"](http://www.zrinity.com/developers/mx/undocumentation/query.cfm), and I can see how to create a `coldfusion.sql.QueryTable` from a `ResultSet`, but not the other way around. So, how can I extract the `java.sql.ResultSet` from a ColdFusion ( `coldfusion.sql.QueryTable` ) query object?

Comment: Out of interest what are you trying to do with the resultset that you need the java.sql.resultset for?

Comment: I'm trying to use some existing java code to manipulate my query, however the code takes in a java.sql.ResultSet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

coldfusion.sql.QueryTable implements javax.sql.RowSet, which extends java.sql.ResultSet

Thus, as you discovered, you don't need to do anything. A ColdFusion query is already a Java ResultSet.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out all I had to do was pass in my coldfusion.sql.QueryTable object...don't know why it works, unless ColdFusion is doing some sort of magic casting under the hood.